# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 (simulator only)

Tags: c++, ios-simulator

Well, I've been porting our game engine onto iOS and bumped into a weird problem.
Our engine defines templated String class that is specialized for char and wchar_t. This class has a static "s_empty" property:

```
// MyString.h
namespace MyEngine
{
    template <typename T> class String
    {
        ...
        static const String s_empty;
    };
    ...
}

//MyString.cpp
namespace MyEngine
{
    template <> String<char> const String<char>::s_empty;
    template <> String<wchar_t> const String<wchar_t>::s_empty;
    // Yes, compiler forces me to start with "template <>"
    ...
}
```

Another module of the project utilizes this variable:

```
const MyEngine::String<wchar_t> &f()
{
    return MyEngine::String<wchar_t>::s_empty;
}
```

This stuff has been working perfectly for ages on different platforms and for various compilers: MSVC+PC86, Codewarrior+NDS and Wii. And it works for iOS on device, but not on simulator!
On simulator, linker generates an error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "MyEngine::String<wchar_t>::s_empty"

Help! )

P.S. "Compile Sources As" is set to "Objective-C++".

Comment: You may need to add some information regarding the specialisation to the header so that when the linker comes across the symbols it can correctly link into the object file that contains the reference.